# Why does docker exec command fail?

Tags: docker

My server is on Centos7.

I'm trying to go into my docker container.

```
[MyServer test]$ docker exec -it MyDocker /bin/bash
failed to open stdin fifo SomeComplicatedCharacterSequence-stdin: stat SomeComplicatedCharacterSequence-stdin: no such file or directory: unknown
```

This command worked before, but now it doesn't work.

What I changed is /etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo for another reason.

When I inspect my docker image,

```
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/bash",
                "--login",
                "-c"
            ],
```

CMD shows /bin/bash.

How can I resolve this??

Any thought appreciated :)

Comment: Is SomeComplicatedCharacterSequence a placeholder for something else? Can you share examples of what it looks like, or at least summarize what you replaced and why?

Answer (score 0):

I stopped and removed the container, and re-run.

If docker run command fails, refer to here.
https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/813#issuecomment-661725238

This issue seems to have to do with version issues.

The above error occurred after I ran `sudo yum update`.